# Does Google penalize for too many redirects from different domains?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect

This is a follow up question to  [Archiving web content annually. One site or sites by year?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29986/archiving-web-content-annually-one-site-or-sites-by-year)

We are completing the import of tens of thousands scientific abstracts into a single site.  The most recent two years of abstracts were hosted on separate domains (conference2012.org, conference2011.org) and represents around 3,000 pages.

I have the ability to add redirects to every single document on the smaller sites and redirect to the new, main site.  However, I am uncertain if Google will slap a Panda, Penguin, or Farmer penalty on the new site for receiving so many redirects from two other domains. But if I don't redirect, I'm concerned that I'll get nailed by the duplicate content penalty before the old sites de-index.

How do I set up this type of migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging a small number of sites into one shouldn't be a problem.

In fact, Matt Cutts made a webmaster help video expressly for this situation: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7M22teF3Ho